# My useState function doesn't update the object at first try after an "await" function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a component called "Confirm" in which there's a message with a button which confirms deleting an agent.

When you click on the button, it invokes the `confirmHandler` which calls the `deleteAgent` function from a higher component.

The deleteAgent is an async function which fetches the backend and then it should update a flag with `setFlagDelete(false)` so the the message disappears.

The issue is that the deleting process actually happens, but the `useState` object doesn't update on the first click on "confirm" button but on the second. So the confirmation message waits for the second click.

However, when I remove the "await" everything works fine.

Why does this happen and how can I keep a normal work flow while keeping the "await"?

The deleting function:

```
const  deleteAgent = async () => {
    try{
      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/deleteagent", {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        tz: agentToDelete.id
      })
      })
      var index;
      for(let i = 0; i < allAgents.length; i++){
        if(allAgents[i].tz == agentToDelete.id){
          index = i;
         }
       }
      updateAllAgents([...allAgents.slice(0, index), ...allAgents.slice(index + 1)]);
      for(let j = 0; j < allCities.length; j++){
        if(allCities[j] == agentToDelete.city){
          index = j;
        }
      }
      updateAllCities([...allCities.slice(0, index), ...allCities.slice(index + 1)]);
      setFlagDelete(false);
      
    } catch (err){
      console.log(err);
    };
  };
```

the component how it's rendering

```
{(flagDelete == true) && <Confirm agent={agentToDelete} cancel={cancelDelete} confirm={deleteAgent} />}
```

the Confirm component:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Confirm.module.css";

const Confirm = (props) => {
  const cancelHandler = () => {
    props.cancel();
  };

  const confirmHandler = () => {
    props.confirm();
  };

  return(
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <p className={styles.text}>Are you sure you want to delete {props.agent.fname} {props.agent.lname}, id: {props.agent.id} ? </p>
      <div className={styles.buttons}>
        <button type="button" onClick={confirmHandler}>Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={cancelHandler}>Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Confirm;
```

I tried putting the `setFlagDelete` function as a third argument to the fetch function, but then the code stops just after the fetching.

Comment: what are u refering here ' However, when I remove the "await" everything works fine.' await before fetch or anywhere else in the code, as far as I can see deleteAgent() is async function  so now it will always return a Promise, so I guess you also need to use await with that function  inorder to make sure the promise if fulfilled state. confirmHandler () just simply call the props.cofirm() which seems to be wrong here. will love to have a look at the issue on sanbox. thanks

Comment: i could directly call props.confirm and skip the handler. about the "await", what i meant is removing that from before the fetch, solves my issue somehow. but we dont want to do that of course.